# Android app login screen not loading

Tags: java, android, firebase, authentication

I'm trying to implement sign up and login activities within my app.  It's using the firebase login attributes and is already connected to firebase.  My sign up screen loads and is functional, but when I click the button to do the log in with an already made account, the activity doesn't load.

Sign up java

```
package com.sjappdev.houstonrocketsteamapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
private Button btnSignIn, btnSignUp, btnResetPassword;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private FirebaseAuth auth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

    //Get Firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_button);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    btnResetPassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);

    btnResetPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
        }
    });

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, LoginActivityB.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (password.length() < 6) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password too short, enter minimum 6 characters!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //create user
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(SignupActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

}

Login java

```
package com.sjappdev.houstonrocketsteamapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class LoginActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Button btnSignup, btnLogin, btnReset;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivityB.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        // set the view now
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        btnSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivityB.this, SignupActivity.class));
            }
        });

        btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivityB.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
            }
        });

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //authenticate user
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivityB.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // there was an error
                                    if (password.length() < 6) {
                                        inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivityB.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivityB.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.sjappdev.houstonrocketsteamapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the    user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/rocketsicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/rocketsicon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SignupActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <!-- <data android:mimeType="image/png" /> -->
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PlayersActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <!-- <data android:mimeType="image/png" /> -->
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".StaffActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <!-- <data android:mimeType="image/png" /> -->
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Settings"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <!-- <data android:mimeType="image/png" /> -->
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <!-- <data android:mimeType="image/png" /> -->
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name=".EditPrefs"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <!-- <data android:mimeType="image/png" /> -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivityB"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <!-- <data android:mimeType="image/png" /> -->
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My guess was the problem lied in the manifest, but it seems to be fine.  Just not sure why the activity isn't working.  It's error free.  Could the error be my lack of toolbar or action bar?

Thanks,
Samuel

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting ? 
what does your mainactivity class look like? 
if the auth for the current user is NOT NULL, meaning, if there is auth, it will load your mainactivity class. It will skip all other code. try removing finish(); from this too, it might do something.

```
public class LoginActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Button btnSignup, btnLogin, btnReset;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivityB.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
```

Comment: Yes, I actually figured out that the auth was skipping everything and my MainActivity was the one that wasn't loading.  I appreciate it.